# How to link RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW function?

Tags: winapi, winsock

I am not able to link RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW(). This is a simplified version of my program.

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

#include <MSTcpIP.h>

HRESULT doMAin()
{
    LONG error;
    PSOCKADDR_IN sin4;

    error = RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW(
        L"127.0.0.1",
        TRUE,
        &sin4->sin_addr,
        &sin4->sin_port);

    return S_OK;
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW@16
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use [`inet_addr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563(v=vs.85).aspx)? I know it doesn't handle the port, but your sample code doesn't pass that (and uses a literal...).

Comment: @Deanna, does this function is not common?

Comment: I don't know, I've only used `inet_addr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"An import library containing the RtlIpv4StringToAddressEx function is not included in the Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) released for Windows Vista. The RtlIpv4StringToAddressEx function is included in the Ntdll.lib import library included in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK). An application could also use the GetModuleHandle and GetProcAddress functions to retrieve the function pointer from the Ntdll.dll and call this function."

from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If there was a lib to pragma comment, it would be Ntdll.lib. To repeat the docs, you can either grab the one from the DDK, or GetProcAddress the sucker.

`GetProcAddress`ing would look like

```
  typedef LONG (NTAPI *pfRtlIpv4StringToAddressEx)(PCWSTR,BOOLEAN,IN_ADDR *,PUSHORT);
  pfRtlIpv4StringToAddressEx pRtlIpv4StringToAddressEx = (pfRtlIpv4StringToAddressEx)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW");
  error = (*pRtlIpv4StringToAddressEx)(
    L"127.0.0.1",
    TRUE,
    &sin4->sin_addr,
    &sin4->sin_port);
```